# i found an error when i use an arthmitic orperetion in kotlin in this code can any one till me what the error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
}
```

ConvertButton.setOnClickListener {

```
        val amount = amountEt.text.toString().toDouble()
        val tofield = values[Tomune.text.toString()] 
        val fromfield = values[from_menu.text.toString()]
        var result = amount * (tofield!!.div( fromfield!!)) // error apper when i use .div() or / sign 

        showentext.setText(result.toString())
    }
```

}

Comment: What is the data type of `values` ?

Comment: Post the actual error, it tells you what the problem is (and will say what type you're trying to use `div` with). It could even be a null pointer exception since you're doing lookups that may not have a value stored - we don't know unless we have the error info

Answer (score 0):

`val tofield = values[Tomune.text.toString()]`  Tomune.text.toString() is a string you have not converted it to a int. Hence you are trying to access the values array by the string which is probably returning you a value that you can't divide

Comment: The `String` there is a lookup key for `values`, so `tofield` might not be a string. But whatever's stored in there, you can't use `div` with it!